# Are there any plugins for browser for changing website colors?

Tags: windows, web-browser, css, accessibility

Is there any plugin for web browsers like Firefox or Chrome, which will automatically process CSS sheets to change page colors to be darker?

For example, if there is white or light background on website page, it could replace it with dark gray or other colors so it will be much less stress to my eyes.

I am asking because I have such a problem with my eyes. If there are such plugins, I believe, I could work better and longer. Manually editing CSS is the last thing I will ever try to do as it is easier for a plugin to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Firefox, you can use [Night Mode Pro](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/night-mode-pro/), [Night Mode Eye Guard](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/eyeguard/), or [Black Background and White Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/black-background-white-text/).  All three extensions will automatically convert light backgrounds to dark backgrounds.

There was also an extension called [Night Mode Page Dim](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/search/?q=night%20mode%20page%20dim), which was excellent and available until just recently.  Perhaps it will be available in the future.

You may also appreciate [Color Transform](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/color-transform/), [Page Colors & Fonts Buttons](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/page-colors-fonts-buttons/), [Color That Site](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/color-that-site/), and [ToggleDocumentColors](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/toggledocumentcolors-198916/).  Each of these is a touch more complex than my first two recommendations, but also much more flexible.  They allow you to customize the colors of any page to ones more suitable for you.

I've used all the above extensions for different purposes, and you can't go wrong with any of them.

As Turner mentioned, [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) is excellent if you want a tool to affect the colors of your entire system.

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/)? It doesn't do exactly what you've asked for, but I think it could still help you. F.lux is a program which reduces the amount of blue light that your computer emits and can greatly reduce eyestrain and helps your eyes adapt to the time of day.

Comment: This magic thing is just great too! I still hope ill find a plugin for CSS but you've already made my life. Very good recommendation if anyone will have such problem.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox natively have a "read mode". It can activate from the url bar, just press an icon and the page adapts to read.

Comment: just makes it hard to read because all get in a single text block. I didn't use firefox's read mode, but i used it before so i am sure firefox is same. It does not reduce amount of colorness (lightness) and just do not affect colors in the way i've asked

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Your answer is somewhat short. We prefer answers to be full fledged personal recommendations rather then "This would work". Could you improve your answer by adding a screenshot? Maybe add a link to a post of the firefox developers where they introduce that feature? Mentioning negative stuff that would be good as well. (e.G. I just used this feature here on SO but then I only see the question, but not the answers...) Tell us more about why you think this function is what solves the problem. Hope to see you around!